# Override approval page

Tags: custom-button, approval-process

I have object MyReports and I generate pdf attachment after data of record is approved.
Right now, after approval, I'm handling pdf creation with REST call in trigger, is there way to override whole approval page or just Approve button to allow pdf creation without REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create custom approval process button. One of the ways is to create custom JavaScript button that will just redirect to submit page.
Something like this:

```
navigateToUrl('/p/process/Submit?id={!yourObejctId}&retURL=%2F{!yourObejctId}');
```

Other is to create button that will redirect to custom page and you can submit for approval in controller. check: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_process_example.htm

Comment: thanks, I forgot that I can not just start approval by apex, but also finish it.